# Lightweight pickle for basic types in python?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

All I want to do is serialize and unserialize tuples of strings or ints.

I looked at pickle.dumps() but the byte overhead is significant. Basically it looks like it takes up about 4x as much space as it needs to. Besides, all I need is basic types and have no need to serialize objects.

marshal is a little better in terms of space but the result is full of nasty \x00 bytes. Ideally I would like the result to be human readable.

I thought of just using repr() and eval(), but is there a simple way I could accomplish this without using eval()?

This is getting stored in a db, not a file. Byte overhead matters because it could make the difference between requiring a TEXT column versus a varchar, and generally data compactness affects all areas of db performance.

Comment: the overhead *is* significant for a pickle dump!

Comment: The Bristol Stool chart is an excellent resource for identifying what type of nasty \x00 bytes you may be experiencing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bristol_Stool_Chart.png

Comment: wheres the problem with configparser?

Comment: Human readable format have a lot of overhead by design.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), at least the generated `dumps` are readable with many other languages.

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) http://json.org is a subset of JavaScript syntax (ECMA-262 3rd edition) used as a lightweight data interchange format.

Answer (score 8):

personally i would use [yaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML).  it's on par with json for encoding size, but it can represent some more complex things (e.g. classes, recursive structures) when necessary.

```
In [1]: import yaml
In [2]: x = [1, 2, 3, 'pants']
In [3]: print(yaml.dump(x))
[1, 2, 3, pants]

In [4]: y = yaml.load('[1, 2, 3, pants]')
In [5]: y
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3, 'pants']
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you're not using the right protocol:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> a = range(1, 100)
>>> len(pickle.dumps(a))
492
>>> len(pickle.dumps(a, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))
206
```

See the documentation for [pickle data formats](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format).

Answer (score 6):

If you need a space efficient solution you can use Google Protocol buffers.

[Protocol buffers - Encoding](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html)

[Protocol buffers - Python Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/pythontutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are some persistence builtins mentioned in the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/persistence.html) but I don't think any of these is remarkable smaller in the produced filesize.

You could alway use the [configparser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) but there you only get string, int, float, bool.

Answer (score 0):

"the byte overhead is significant"

Why does this matter?  It does the job.  If you're running low on disk space, I'd be glad to sell you a 1Tb for $500.

Have you run it?  Is performance a problem?  Can you demonstrate that the performance of serialization is **the** problem?

"I thought of just using repr() and eval(), but is there a simple way I could accomplish this without using eval()?"

Nothing simpler than repr and eval.

What's wrong with eval?

Is is the "someone could insert malicious code into the file where I serialized my lists" issue?

Who -- specifically -- is going to find and edit this file to put in malicious code?  Anything you do to secure this (i.e., encryption) removes "simple" from it.

Comment: The problem with eval is: you need to do the errorhandling yourself (e.g. typos).

Comment: What errors are you expecting?  You produced it with repr.  What can happen?

Comment: Why does this matter?: it could make the difference between being able to store it in a varchar or a text column

Who -- specifically -- is going to find and edit this file to put in malicious code?: standard privilege escalation vulnerability.

Comment: like i said: typos. He said he wants a human readable file so: when human reads he also writes...just because he can.

Answer (score -1):

Luckily there is solution which uses COMPRESSION, and solves 
the general problem involving any arbitrary Python object 
including new classes. Rather than micro-manage mere 
tuples sometimes it's better to use a DRY tool.
Your code will be more crisp and readily refactored 
in similar future situations.

y_serial.py module :: warehouse Python objects with SQLite

"Serialization + persistance :: in a few lines of code, compress and annotate Python objects into SQLite; then later retrieve them chronologically by keywords without any SQL. Most useful "standard" module for a database to store schema-less data."

http://yserial.sourceforge.net

[If you are still concerned, why not stick those tuples in 
a dictionary, then apply y_serial to the dictionary. 
Probably any overhead will vanish due to the transparent 
compression in the background by zlib.]

As to readability, the documentation also gives details on 
why cPickle was selected over json.